# Ionic cordova emulate android Doesn't Open Emulator

Tags: android, ios, node.js, angular, cordova

**I want to run Ionic cordova emulate android or even ios but none launches the respective emulators.**

*During the build I get the below warnings / messages:*

```
 cordova emulate android Android Studio project detected 
 (node:1065) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
 rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a
 string or buffer, not object (node:1065) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:
 Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
 rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
 with a non-zero exit code.

 [OK] Your app has been deployed.
      Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?

 No valid rules have been specified [10:19:02]  lint finished in 1.99 s
```

- Even tho it says your app has been deployed the emulator doesn't
  launch.  Where do I look for to sort this out?

*Below are my settings
Framework :*

```
 3.9.2
App Scripts : 2.1.4
Angular Core : 4.1.3
Angular Compiler CLI : 4.1.3
Node : 8.9.1
OS : Mac OS High Sierra
```

*Thanks for the help guys*

Comment: Facing same issue in Ionic 3 while using cordova-fcm-plugin for push notifications.